# In JSF a file name with style.css is not supported, why?

Tags: jsf, stylesheet

When I was linking the Css file using the following tagline

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css" target="body"/>
```

and I have the arranged directory structure as `WebContent->resources->css->style.css`
 and I was getting result code on browser as `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="RES_NOT_FOUND" />`

But when I have changed the file name to styles.css, it worked but I didn't get the reason that what was the problem with style.css.

Comment: Did you also changed the tag to reference styles.css?

Comment: yes, in the tag also it's needed to change the value of property "name" as "styles.css"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you have set your resource files inside your project. Since this looks to be your actual folder structure:

```
resources
- css
  - style.css
```

You have to call your CSS file like this:

```
<h:outputStylesheet name="css/style.css" />
```

More info:

- [What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11988415/1065197)